# Why does my code always return HTTP status 200?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

My PHP scripts are processed by the `php-fpm` docker container, I also have the `nginx` docker container running to accept requests.

I am developing a small JSON API service with the Lumen framework. I am trying to handle an exception in my `Handler.php`.

```php
case ($e instanceof Exception\NotFoundHttpException):
    return ResponseProvider::render(
        new ResponseMessagesDTO(
            new Messages\ENTITY_NOT_FOUND_Message
        ),
        exception: $e
    );
```

The code may look scary, but I am just formulating a response for the client.

The code should return HTTP status `404`, but it always returns `200`.

If an attempt is made to give a similar (standard) answer, then everything works fine.

```php
case ($e instanceof Exception\NotFoundHttpException):
    return response()->json(['data' => 'data'], 404);
```

Then it returns `404` as expected. The problem is that when I run this project through the built-in PHP server everything works fine, that is if I run:

```
$ php -S local: 8000 -t ./public
```

And then I make a request:

```php
case ($e instanceof Exception\NotFoundHttpException):
    return ResponseProvider::render(
        new ResponseMessagesDTO(
            new messages\ENTITY_NOT_FOUND_Message
        ),
        exception: $e
    );
```

**ResponseProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

use phpcommon\http\ResponseMessagesDTO as DTO;

class ResponseProvider
{
   
    public static function render(DTO $body = null, Cookie $cookie = null , Exception $exception = null,   string $type = "json")
    {
        $data = $body->serialize();
        
        if($cookie){
            return response()->json($data,$body->getStatus())->cookie($cookie);
        }
        
        return response()->json($data,$body->getStatus());
    }
}
?>
```

**my Nginx configuration**

```yaml
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
          

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/gateway_error.log  debug;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  600;


    server {

        listen 80;

        server_name project.loc;    
            
        root /var/www/app/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        charset utf-8;

        server_tokens off;

        add_header  X-Frame-Options 'SAMEORIGIN';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,preview-file-uuid,access-level,access_level,user-uuid' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;

        error_page  405     =200 $uri;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   fpm:9000;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }


}
```

It returns HTTP status `404` as expected.

The question is why `nginx / php-fpm` scheme always returns `200`, but if you use the standard response method then `404` (as expected) is returned?

But if you use `php -S` then everything works as expected.

Perhaps I am missing something in the `php-fpm`'s config?

Comment: Super personal recommendation, stick to `PSR`, doing `return ResponseProvider :: render` etc. all with spaces is not standard, avoid that 100%, also avoid `catch (...) :`, it should be `catch (...) { ... }`. Configure your IDE to follow standards as the code is not readable. Also, share what does `ResponseProvider` do as we are not magicians to guess your code. I am sure there is a problem or similar there.

Comment: Maybe there's a redirect triggered by nginx with the rendered exception response? Check the network tab of the browser to see (make sure you check "preserve log" or something like that to not discard the redirects)

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for the answer! I have attached the code, but as mentioned above, the code works fine if you run the project like this: `php -S local: 8000 -t. / Public`

Comment: @Mila share your `nginx` configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `error_page  405     =200 $uri;`.

Comment: unfortunately it won't help as this is just a CORS plug. My application does not process OPTIOS requests that the browser sends for CORS and I made such a gag that the server would respond 200 when php typed 405, but the server returned 400 or 301 or any other error if returned in the standard way without a ResponseProvider

`return response ('Hello World', 401)`